# Low profile windows AMI for EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

Are there any trusted low profile Windows AMIs out there?
By low profile I mean client class windows, with minimal disk use.
Basically I need to provide a number of clients with remote access terminals for an education project.
The smallest windows installation provided by amazon is a windows server 2008 (if I am not mistaken) and it needs a 30GB disk.
Are there other trusted (I mean from trusted sources) AMIs that I can use that use smaller disks? on the Micro instances.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wondering why you need that. Because EBS is really cheap, so I'm discarding it.

Comment: Cheap is relative, isn't it? when you need to squeeze your costs as much as possible you would think of using smaller than 30GB harddisks when you don't need them! That's my only reason. Although there might be others who have other reasons, if they want to restrict their users available space if they need to maintain back ups or ...